# Finding the distance

Tags: python

im trying to create a function that takes a list of coordinators that represent 'friends' houses' and another coordinate ie (0,0) representing a starting point. Its supposed to find the distance from the starting point, then each of the friend's houses then returns to the starting place using the method (x1-x2) + (y1-y2), with the function returning the overall distance travelled. I get indexing could be involved as well as iterating through all the list of coordinates but other than that I'm a bit stumped.
so far I've got:

```
def total_travel(houses, start):

        value1 = start[0] - houses[0] + start[1] - houses[1]

    for i in houses:

        start[i] - houses[i] + start[i] - houses[I]
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: So let me get this straight you have a list of friend's house coordinates (x,y)  and want to total the distances between each after getting the distance between the first coordinate and the starting point?

Comment: yes, from the starting point to the first coordinate in the list, then add that value to the total distance from the first coordinate in list to second, iterating through the whole list of tuple coordinates, then finally the distance from the last house back to the starting point

Comment: Yes it changes the negatives to positive. Check my answer to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
houses =[(0,1), (2,0), (3,3)]
start = (1,3)
total=abs(start[1]-houses[0][1]) + abs(start[0]-houses[0][0])
print(total)
for i in range(1,len(houses)):
    total+=abs(houses[i][1]-houses[i-1][1]) + abs(houses[i][0]-houses[i-1][0])
print(total)
if len(houses)>1:
    total+=abs(start[1]-houses[-1][1]) + abs(start[0]-houses[-1][0])
print(total)
```

So it uses abs || to calculate the difference between the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) first by the starting and first element, then the total between all elements in houses, and then the last element.

```
|y2-y1|+|x2-x1|
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to create a helper function to calculate distance given 2D points:

```
def calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(x1,x2,y1,y2):
    return abs(
        (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2
    )
```

then assign your data:

```
startingPoint = (1,3)
houses = [(0,1), (2,0), (3,3)]
```

then get the distance between the houses:

```
distanceBetweenHouses = 0
previousHouse = None
for house in houses:
    if previousHouse == None:
        previousHouse = house
        continue
    distanceBetweenHouses += calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(previousHouse[0], house[0], previousHouse[1], house[1])
    previousHouse = house
```

Then calculate the distance from the starting point to first house, and starting point to last house:

```
distanceToFirstHouse = calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(startingPoint[0], houses[0][0], startingPoint[1], houses[0][1])
distanceToLastHouse = calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(startingPoint[0], houses[-1][0], startingPoint[1], houses[-1][1])
```

Then sum them all:

```
totalDistance = distanceBetweenHouses + distanceToFirstHouse + distanceToLastHouse
```

Programming is like telling a story. Breaking up your problem into smaller pieces makes it easier to approach and helps with maintaining it.

Comment: no problem. Do note I used `abs( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)` to calculate distance instead of the formula you provided `abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)` but feel free to switch them out in the function, it's easy.